# python dataframe When converting Int to Str, .0 is added at the end

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

print(dataframe)

```
      Total Price      test_num                                        
0           71.7       2.04256e+14 
1           39.5       2.04254e+14 
2           82.2       2.04188e+14
3           42.9       2.04171e+14
```

I have an error when uploading to Mongo db and converting it to Str.

print(data_frame.astype(str))

```
 Total Price     test_num                        
0           71.7  204255705072224.0           
1           39.5  204253951078915.0         
2           82.2  204188075120577.0          
3           42.9  204171098699772.0
```

When converting Int to Str, .0 is added at the end.
How can I effectively eliminate .0?
thank you

Comment: df = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace('0.0', ""))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) by `int64`:

```
df['test_num'] = df['test_num'].astype('int64')
#alternative
#df['test_num'] = df['test_num'].astype(np.int64)
print (df)
   Total  Price         test_num
0      0   71.7  204256000000000
1      1   39.5  204254000000000
2      2   82.2  204188000000000
3      3   42.9  204171000000000
```

**Explanation**:

You can check [`dtype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) of converted column - it return `float64`.

```
print (df['test_num'].dtype)
float64
```

After converting to string it remove exponential notation and cast to `float`s, so added traling `0`:

```
print (df['test_num'].astype('str'))
0    204256000000000.0
1    204254000000000.0
2    204188000000000.0
3    204171000000000.0
Name: test_num, dtype: object
```

Comment: I'll delete my answer if you can provide an explanation. This doesn't *explain* what's going wrong.

Comment: @jpp - I try it, but need more time.

Comment: @jpp - I try a bit, but it should be better, [so post question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325032/converting-exponential-notation-numbers-to-strings-explanation)

Comment: I just saw your answer. I'm sorry.