# Converting exponential notation numbers to strings - explanation

Tags: python, pandas, casting, floating-point, integer

I have `DataFrame` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51321769/2901002):

```
temp=u"""Total,Price,test_num
0,71.7,2.04256e+14
1,39.5,2.04254e+14
2,82.2,2.04188e+14
3,42.9,2.04171e+14"""
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp))

print (df)
   Total  Price      test_num
0      0   71.7  2.042560e+14
1      1   39.5  2.042540e+14
2      2   82.2  2.041880e+14
3      3   42.9  2.041710e+14
```

If convert `float`s to `string`s get trailing `0`:

```
print (df['test_num'].astype('str'))
0    204256000000000.0
1    204254000000000.0
2    204188000000000.0
3    204171000000000.0
Name: test_num, dtype: object
```

Solution is convert `float`s to `integer64`:

```
print (df['test_num'].astype('int64'))
0    204256000000000
1    204254000000000
2    204188000000000
3    204171000000000
Name: test_num, dtype: int64

print (df['test_num'].astype('int64').astype(str))
0    204256000000000
1    204254000000000
2    204188000000000
3    204171000000000
Name: test_num, dtype: object
```

---

Question is why it convert this way?

I add this poor explanation, but feels it should be better:

**Poor explanation**:

You can check [`dtype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) of converted column - it return `float64`.

```
print (df['test_num'].dtype)
float64
```

After converting to string it remove exponential notation and cast to `float`s, so added traling `0`:

```
print (df['test_num'].astype('str'))
0    204256000000000.0
1    204254000000000.0
2    204188000000000.0
3    204171000000000.0
Name: test_num, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is just how `numpy` converts `float` types to `str`, it will add a trailing `.0`. Converting a float value using `str()` produces the same result, so this is just the _stringification_ of  a `float` type number.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa - Be free expand comment and add answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use pd.read_csv to import data and do not define datatypes,
pandas makes an educated guess and in this case decides, that column
values like "2.04256e+14" are best represented by a float value.

This, converted back to string adds a ".0". As you corrently write,
converting to int64 fixes this.

If you know that the column has int64 values only before input (and
no empty values, which np.int64 cannot handle), you can force this type on import to avoid the unneeded conversions.

```
import numpy as np

temp=u"""Total,Price,test_num
0,71.7,2.04256e+14
1,39.5,2.04254e+14
2,82.2,2.04188e+14
3,42.9,2.04171e+14"""

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), dtype={2: np.int64})

print(df)
```

returns

```
   Total  Price         test_num
0      0   71.7  204256000000000
1      1   39.5  204254000000000
2      2   82.2  204188000000000
3      3   42.9  204171000000000
```